# Best book on the decision-theoretic justification of bayesian probability

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation, bayesian, decision-theory

> The use of Bayesian probabilities as the basis of Bayesian inference has been supported by several arguments, such as Cox axioms, the Dutch book argument, arguments based on decision theory and de Finetti's theorem.

> A decision-theoretic justification of the use of Bayesian inference (and hence of Bayesian probabilities) was given by Abraham Wald, who proved that every admissible statistical procedure is either a Bayesian procedure or a limit of Bayesian procedures.[26] Conversely, every Bayesian procedure is admissible.[27]

*[Wikipedia: Bayesian Probability - Justification of Bayesian Probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability#Justification_of_Bayesian_probabilities)*

What's the best book on the decision-theoretic justification of bayesian probability? I found a few books on the topic:

- The Bayesian choice - Christian P Robert
- Bayesian Theory - Adrian Smith and José-Miguel Bernardo
- Statistical Decision Theory and Bayesian Analysis - Jim Berger

Which one of these books is the best and most relevant to the topic? Are there any other books that are better than these?

Comment: Check out [Principles of Uncertainty](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~kadane/principles.pdf) by Joesph Kadane.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think that book is about subjective-bayesian/deFinetti probability theory. Are there any books that justify probability theory purely using decision theory?

Comment: What do you think "deFinetti probability theory" is?

Comment: "In 1937, de Finetti published a work which expressed a philosophy somewhat like ours ..., but also sought to establish the foundations of probability theory itself on the notion of ‘coherence’. This means, roughly speaking, that one should assign and manipulate probabilities so that one cannot be made a sure loser in betting based on them." - Edwin Jaynes, _Probability Theory: The Logic of Science_ p. 655. 



What I meant by "deFinetti probability theory" is justifying bayesian probability using deFinetti's Dutch book argument like Jaynes mentions in his book.

Comment: I'm looking for a book on the decision-theoretic justification for bayesian probability that was given by Abraham Wald

Comment: I was being a bit glib. My point was that de Finetti's approach **is** decision-theoretic. But never mind. If you're interested in Wald's work in particular, then why not just read his books and papers first?

Comment: Your question just isn't very clearly stated, and your comments aren't clarifying things. What do you mean by "decision-theoretic foundations"? What does it mean to "prove probability theory using decision theory"?

Comment: @aduh Sorry about that, I've edited my question. Hopefully, it's more clear now. By proving probability theory, I only meant justifying its use (as Wald did). There seemed to be a lot of books on the topic so I wasn't sure which one to start with. Are you familiar with Wald's works on the topic? Do they give a good exposition of these concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the third you mentioned and it is a good textbook, even if my favourite is [Box Tiao](https://www.academia.edu/7915390/_George_E_P_Box_George_C_Tiao_Bayesian_Infere_Book_ZZ_org_)

Comment: Thank you. Does Berger justify/derive bayesian probability theory using decision theory or does he focus on the applications of bayesian methods in making decisions?

Comment: @HaziqMuhammad : it's a very complete book including Bayesian Analysis (Chapers 1-4), Bayesian methods in making decision under uncertainty (i.e. minimax, and Bayesian sequential analysis) in Chapters 5-8

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a little confused :). I'm looking for a book that proves probability theory using decision theory. Is that what you meant by Bayesian Analysis?

Comment: @HaziqMuhammad : it's included over there... but I do not know a book with specific focus on that, sorry

Comment: No worries. Thanks a lot for your help! Much appreciated